# В Antd не провяряются поля в форме

Tags: reactjs, ant-design

Добавил значение для полей в форму через useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth) {
    form.setFields(initialPersonalFields)
  }
}, [])
```

Само значение в полях отображается, но они не получают статус валидированных и не стилизуются соответственно, хотя при этом сабмит с проверкой валидации отрабатывает правильно и видит их как валидированные и не выдает ошибку. Eсли начать писать в этих полях то тоже начинают правильно отрабатывать, когда нужно выдает ошибку, когда заполняю в ручную правильно ставит статус "успешно".